# Making a dropdown that contains radio buttons accessible

Tags: drop-down-menu, radio-button, accessibility, wai-aria, wcag

I have a dropdown that is stylized to contain radio buttons as its options/selections. I am a little confused about how to make this accessible (WCAG 2.1 compliant). Should I treat the closed drop down as a regular drop down, but once it opens, I should treat the inside of it as radio buttons with radio button keyboard keys navigation?

[Screenshot of the dropdown containing radio buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfp13.png)

If I can not change the design, what is the best approach in making it accessible?